# Sql query to get user id having latest date time

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have one table having

```
**user_id** | **date**
1           | 2012-10-18 09:34:4
3           | 2012-10-18 09:34:54
5           | 2012-10-17 09:14:54
6           | 2012-10-17 09:13:24
4           | 2012-10-16 08:34:54
9           | 2012-10-16 08:34:54
```

What I want is user_id with latest date-time i.e

```
**user_id** | **date**
3           | 2012-10-18 09:34:54
5           | 2012-10-17 09:14:54
4           | 2012-10-16 08:34:54
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select * from (
   select user_id, date
   from mytable
   order by date desc ) x
group by date(date);
```

Note: This is a mysql-only solution, but it works!

Answer (score 1):

Use `GROUP BY` on the date part of your `date` column (which seems to be of type `DATETIME`):

```
SELECT user_id, MAX(date) FROM table GROUP BY DATE(date);
```

Comment: This will not work as two users are there with same date but different time. I want only one user eg. 3 from 1,3 where user 3 has latest time on same date

Comment: SELECT user_id FROM TB_NAME ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 0,1

Comment: @user1710937 ah I get it now. Your question was not very clear on that. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

To get one user with latest date time, try this

```
SELECT user_id FROM TB_NAME ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 0,1
```

Answer (score 0):

if you need only one user

```
SELECT 
    MAX(date) as LatestDateTime
FROM 
    mytable
```

And for multiple users

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    mytable
ORDER By date DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
SELECT user_id, max(date) from user group by user_id
```

or

```
select user_id from user where date = (select max(date) from user)
```

Answer (score 0):

And another one [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/06598/3/0)

```
select user_id, `date`
from mytable t1
join (select max(`date`) as max_date
      from mytable
      group by date(`date`)) t2 on t1.`date` = t2.max_date
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, I hope it works.

```
    SELECT t.user_id, t.date
    FROM table t
    WHERE t.date = (SELECT MAX(t2.date) FROM table t2 GROUP BY t2.date HAVING t2.date = t.date)
```

Goodluck!